# Prove that the sequence $f_{n}(x)=\arctan(x^{2n})$ converges in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

I have to prove this fact.
$$a_{n}(x)=\arctan(x^{2n})$$
converges on $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ to $\pi/2-\chi_{(-1,1)}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.
($\chi_{(-1,1)}=1$in such interval, $0$ otherwise).
Any idea to start? Thank you.

Comment: please stop using $x$ for both the function and the variable

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $a_\infty=\frac{\pi}{2} (1-\chi_{(-1,1)})=\frac{\pi}{2}\chi_{\mathbb R\setminus (-1,1)} $. By definition of convergence of distributions you have to show $$\int_{\mathbb R} a_n(t) \varphi(t)dt \to \int_{\mathbb R} a_\infty(t) \varphi(t)dt.$$ 
This follows from $a_n(t)\to \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $|t|> 1$ and $a_n(t)\to 0$ for $|t|<1$. To interchange limits and integrals you can use Lebegue's theorem on dominated convergence.

Comment: "This follows from $a_n(t)\to \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $|t|\ge 1$" That should be $|t|>1.$

Comment: Right, of course. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, which is the dominating function for the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem? $g(x)=\pi/2$ for $t \in (-1,1)$? Thank you.

Comment: $\frac {\pi}{2}|\varphi|$ is dominating.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I try to finish the problem. So I have $$a_n(x)=\arctan(x^{2n})$$
I see that this is a even function. 

If $0<|x|<1$ I have $a_n(x)\approx x^{2n}\approx0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for small values of $x$.

When $|x|>1$ I have that $x^{2n}$ goes to $+\infty$ and

$a_{n}(+\infty)=\arctan(+\infty)=\pi/2$.

I don't know if this is a rigorous explanation for the fact. What do tou thinking about my try? Thank you.

Comment: Essentially, this is correct. IT depends on your standards of rigor if you or your instructor are happy e.g. with $\arctan (\infty) $.